# Как разгрузить веб-сервер от ajax?

Tags: php, mysql, websocket

Сейчас на сайте всё происходит (автообновление статистики, обмен сообщениями и тд) через AJAX. Знаю, способ не совсем элегантный, но рабочий. Посещают мысли разгрузить БД и веб-сервер от этой нагрузки. Но я не знаю через что это лучше сделать.

Думал за вебсокет-сервер. Нагрузку с веб-сервера он снимет, но к БД она останется прежней, так как все-равно придется вытаскивать из нее актуальные данные. Это поможет только в случае обмена сообщениями на сайте в режиме реального времени.

Какие еще есть технологии, которые помогут? Или объясните, может я что-то не так понимаю.

Comment: данные можно кешировать резличными способами. прямо в оперативной памяти, в запущенных процессах (правда это не о php). В redis или memcached. Так же можно задействовать различные брокеры сообщений, вроде RabbitMQ или ActiveMQ. Вместо вебсокета можно посмотреть еще в сторону server side events. Так же можно использовать вместо MySQL другие СУБД, в которых есть события (вроде postgresql)

Comment: Почему при использовании сокетов нагрузка к бд окажется прежней? При изменении статистики, например, вы обновляете бд и тут же отправляете актуальные данные в ws-сервер, который в свою очередь отправит их всем подписанным клиентам. Бд в таком случае дергается только в момент обновления статистики.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Веб сокет должен снизить нагрузку, поскольку AJAX - это каждый раз авторизация и подобная подготовка, а через веб сокет подготовка будет сделана только один раз